# SUM Using Multiple Criteria to Determine What is Counted & How [Part 1]

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs

[Edited: This has been solved but I made a mess of the original question, so I've edited it for clarity and posterity.]

I'm looking to add the numbers from multiple columns in a row, to come up with some totals. But which columns are counted and how they are used needs to be based on multiple criteria.

Here is an editable demo sheet, noted for clarity and with the desired results:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11Ixj8D5Wl8ZEG2M-9Z1AdGNDpmCP5h9TPLFEdCylQcg/

### **Part 1: Calculating K ("Total Discounts Before Tax")**

**Purpose of K:**

The goal for K is simply to find the total value of the discounts before any tax calculations.

Finally, whenever there is an unknown factor that prevents a directly related 100% known measure for K, then K="??" so it's clear that information is missing and still needed.

**Requirements for Results of K:** (See M for 'Desired Results')

- A single formula used in Header Row K2. Something like an ArrayFormula so that it can be used for the whole column and can have a visible text "LABEL" shown in the cell. [eg "={"LABEL"; ArrayFormula() }" ]
- If C or E or G or I has even one "?", then K="??" [eg E8]
- If C="" and D<>"" (same for E&F,G&H,I&J), then K="??" [eg C6:D6, I3:J3]
- If all 'Discount' and 'is Pre-Tax Columns="" (columns C through J), then K="" [eg ROW13]
- If C=ISNUMBER add C to others (C+E+G+I), but only where they are also =ISNUMBER (After meeting above conditions first) [ROW4, ROW5]

I would be extremely grateful for any help! Thank you!

### **Part 2: Calculating N ("Sales Tax Savings Because of Discounts")**

There's a second even more complicated part that I'm also trying to accomplish in another posted question here:
[SUM Using Multiple Criteria to Determine What is Counted & How [Part 2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77183171/sum-using-multiple-criteria-to-determine-what-is-counted-how-part-2)

Comment: Please limit your question to only 1 per post. Post the other as another question. Also please share what you have done.

Comment: Thank you. I will adjust my question and put the second part into a new post.

Comment: I've made the edits and put up a second post. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[You may try](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11Ixj8D5Wl8ZEG2M-9Z1AdGNDpmCP5h9TPLFEdCylQcg/edit#gid=2036171716):*

```js
=byrow(C3:J,lambda(Σ,let(odd,choosecols(Σ,1,3,5,7),even,choosecols(Σ,2,4,6,8),
      index(ifs(iferror(find("?",join(,odd))),"??",sum((odd="")*(len(even))),"??",counta(odd)=0,,1,sum(odd))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To answer your 1st question:

I have provided a simple formula based on the conditions you've mentioned in C17.

##### Try:

```
=IFERROR(IFS(OR(ISTEXT(C3),ISTEXT(E3),ISTEXT(G3),ISTEXT(I3)),"??",OR(AND(C3="",D3<>""),AND(E3="",F3<>""),AND(G3="",H3<>""),AND(I3="",J3<>"")),"??",ISNUMBER(C3),SUM(C3,E3,G3,I3)),"")
```

Dragged down to column.

##### Result:

[image]

#### Explanation:

Based on your conditions on **C17** here's the breakdown of the formula.

- Using `IFS()` to use multiple conditions.
- Then the first condition is checking if those in Columns C,E,G,I is text, if it is a question mark automatically it is a text using `ISTEXT()` then it will return "??", otherwise it is a number.
- The second condition is checking if the first column in the pair of column "Discount" and "Discount is Pre-tax?" is blank and the other is not, then return "??"
- The third condition is just checking if C3 is number then `SUM()` those columns.

Comment: Thank you!! Is it possible to to use this solution as an array formula in K2? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, thank you very much for the breakdown. I need to learn a lot more and the explanation really helps with that.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't make it more clear that I was hoping for a single formula in a header. I've messed with it some and I feel like I'm close to adapting it but I just can't get there. Thanks again!

Comment: I really appreciate everything and apologize for how clunky and unclear my goals were. I know it's late but I re-clarified the entire original question and I'll do better with future questions. Thank you again!

Comment: Hi @ComputerCandy apologies I was not able to get back to your question sooner. I have noticed that a posted answer is already accepted. Glad your concern is resolved. :) Moving forward please take note to only ask 1 question per post and if possible provide reproducible example. Thanks!