# SUM Using Multiple Criteria to Determine What is Counted & How [Part 2]

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am trying to create an array formula in Google Sheets to calculate the additional savings resulting from applying a discount pretax.

It is based on a simple calculation but becomes more complex because of additional conditions.  For clarity I explain the **Basic Functionality** first, then the **Extra Conditions**.

### Basic Functionality

I have a single `Tax Rate` for each row in column B followed by multiple column pairs (`C:D` , `E:F` , `G:H`), one pair for each discount.

In each column pair, the first column `Discount <id>` contains the dollar amount and the second column `Pretax <id>` contains a flag indicating if the discount was applied pretax.

For each column pair, if the pretax flag is set to "Y", the basic tax savings calculation is the  'discount amount multiplied by the tax rate':

```
=IF(pretax="Y", discount * tax rate,)
```

The formula I am trying to create should go in `N2`.  This formula would return the total `Tax Savings` for each row by calculating the SUM of the savings from each column pair.

###### Sample Data: Basic Functionality

**Note:** Labels have been shortened to save space

|  | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Rate** | **Disc_1** | **Pre_1** | **Disc_2** | **Pre_2** | **Disc_3** | **Pre_3** | **Tax Savings** |
| **2** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | [formula_goes_here] |
| **3** | 5 % | $ 1.00 | `Y` | $ 1.00 | `Y` | $ 1.00 | `Y` | `$ 0.15` |
| **4** | 5 % | $ 1.00 | `Y` | $ 1.00 | `Y` | $ 1.00 | N | `$ 0.10` |
| **5** | 5 % | $ 1.00 | N | $ 1.00 | N | $ 1.00 | N |  |

- In the table above:
  **N3:** `(C3*B3)+(E3*B3)+(G3*B3)=0.15` (Y,Y,Y)
  **N4:** `(C4*B4)+(E4*B4)=0.10` (Y,Y,N)
  **N5:**   (N,N,N)

### Extra Conditions

These conditions override the basic calculation. **`??`** is *always* returned by the formula if *any condition* that follows is matched in *any column pair*.

`??` is returned where there is a:

1. question mark `?` anywhere in any value;
2. numerical value in discount column but paired pretax column isn't `Y` or `N`
3. value in pretax column but paired discount column isn't a numerical value.

###### Sample Data: Extra Conditions

**Note:** Only a single column pair needs to match an extra condition to override the calculation for the entire row (all pairs).

|  | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Rate** | **Disc_1** | **Pre_1** | **Disc_2** | **Pre_2** | **Disc_3** | **Pre_3** | **Tax Savings** |
| **2** |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | [formula_goes_here] |
| **3** | 5 % |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **4** | 5 % |  |  | $ 1.00 | Y | $ 1.00 | Y | `$ 0.10` |
| **5** | 5 % | $ 1.00 | Y | $ 1.00 | Y | $ 1.00 | Y | `$ 0.15` |
| **6** | 5 % | $ 1.00 | N | $ 1.00 | Y | $ 1.00 | Y | `$ 0.10` |
| **7** | 5 % | $ 1.00 | `??` | $ 1.00 | Y | $ 1.00 | Y | `??` |
| **8** | 5 % | $ 1.00 |  | $ 1.00 | Y | $ 1.00 | Y | `??` |
| **9** | 5 % |  | `Y` | $ 1.00 | Y | $ 1.00 | Y | `??` |
| **10** | 5 % |  | `N` | $ 1.00 | Y | $ 1.00 | Y | `??` |
| **11** | 5 % |  | `??` | $ 1.00 | Y | $ 1.00 | Y | `??` |
| **12** | 5 % |  | `?` | $ 1.00 | Y | $ 1.00 | Y | `??` |
| **13** | 5 % | `???` |  | $ 1.00 | Y | $ 1.00 | Y | `??` |

In the example above the formula returns `??` for rows 7 to 13.  The table below shows the conditions that matched and triggered those `??` results.

###### Conditions that Matched

| Row | **Tax Rate** | **Dis_1** | **Pre_1** | Condition 1 | Condition 2 | Condition 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  | `? anywhere` | `Disc=# Pre<>Y/N` | `Pre<>"" Disc=NOT(#)` |
| **7** | 5 % | $ 1.00 | ?? | ✓ | ✓ |  |
| **8** | 5 % | $ 1.00 |  |  | ✓ |  |
| **9** | 5 % |  | Y |  |  | ✓ |
| **10** | 5 % |  | N |  |  | ✓ |
| **11** | 5 % |  | ?? | ✓ |  | ✓ |
| **12** | 5 % |  | ? | ✓ |  | ✓ |
| **13** | 5 % | ??? |  | ✓ |  |  |

I am looking for help with a single formula in `N2` that will behave as described.

[Link to editable demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11Ixj8D5Wl8ZEG2M-9Z1AdGNDpmCP5h9TPLFEdCylQcg/)

---

I have a prior question about other calculations in the the same worksheet:
[SUM Using Multiple Criteria to Determine What is Counted & How [Part 1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77179327/sum-using-multiple-criteria-to-determine-what-is-counted-how-part-1)

Comment: That makes sense. When I get time I'll try to do that or add a screenshot to more directly correlate without have to use a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[You may try](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11Ixj8D5Wl8ZEG2M-9Z1AdGNDpmCP5h9TPLFEdCylQcg/edit#gid=227432971):*

```js
=byrow(C3:J,lambda(Σ,let(odd,choosecols(Σ,1,3,5,7),even,choosecols(Σ,2,4,6,8),
      index(ifs(iferror(find("?",join(,Σ))),"??",counta(odd)>counta(even),"??",(counta(odd)=0)*(counta(even)>0),"??",counta(odd)=0,,1,sum(odd*switch(even,"Y",1,"N",0,))*offset(index(Σ,,1),,-1))))))
```

[image]

Comment: It worked! And I was again able to easily wrap it in an ArrayFormula so I could put it in the header row. Thank you so much for both this solution and the other!

Comment: wrapping the whole *byrow* formula (which itself works array-style by default) within arrayformula() again (even if its to stack it along with header) is not needed (unless you have some specific reason that warrants it)

Comment: I needed to put the formula in the header row. But when I did that, it offset all of the return results by one row. Wrapping it in an ArrayFormula fixed that. Plus I can put a visible text label that shows up instead. (See test sheet 2 ) There's probably a different way I could have done that though.

Comment: I was in way too much of a hurry before. I got rid of the ArrayFormula wrapper and simply added the text label to the BYROW. Thank you again for everything!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=IFERROR(IF(K3="","",REDUCE(0,{IFS(D3 = "Y", IF(ISNUMBER(C3), B3*C3, "??"), (D3="N")+(ISBLANK(C3)*(D3<>"Y")), 0),IFS(F3 = "Y", IF(ISNUMBER(E3), B3*E3, "??"), (F3="N")+(ISBLANK(E3)*(F3<>"Y")), 0),IFS(H3 = "Y", IF(ISNUMBER(G3), B3*G3, "??"), (H3="N")+(ISBLANK(G3)*HD3<>"Y"), 0),IFS(J3 = "Y", IF(ISNUMBER(I3), B3*I3, "??"), (J3="N")+(ISBLANK(I3)*(J3<>"Y")), 0)},LAMBDA(A,B,A+B))),"??")
```

Comment: Shoud you have further question or clarification, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it out in the demo sheet in the "Test 1" sheet but it doesn't quite seem to do the trick unfortunately. It might be close to a full solution but I can't make full sense of it I'm afraid.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please try and check if it works. Thanks!

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Thank you! Is it possible to turn it into a single formula that would work in the header N2? Like an ArrayFormula? Thanks again!

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the complexity of your request, the existing formula isn't possible to work with ArrayFormula.

Comment: I really appreciate everything and apologize for how clunky and unclear my goals were. I know it's late but I re-clarified the entire original question and I'll do better with future questions. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

### Discount Formula

```
={"Formula"; BYROW(B3:J, LAMBDA(r, 
   IF(REGEXMATCH(JOIN(,r), "\?"),"??",
     BYROW(
       BYCOL(SEQUENCE(1,4,2,2), LAMBDA(c, 
         IF((LEN(INDEX(r,,c))>0) * (LEN(INDEX(r,,c+1))=0),
           "??", INDEX(r,,c)))),
       LAMBDA(array, IF(REGEXMATCH(JOIN(,array), "\?"), "??",
         IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(array)))))))))}
```

### Tax Savings Formula

```
={"Formula"; BYROW(B3:J, LAMBDA(r, 
   IF(REGEXMATCH(JOIN(,r), "\?"),"??",
     BYROW(
       BYCOL(SEQUENCE(1,4,2,2), LAMBDA(c, 
         IF((LEN(INDEX(r,,c))>0) * (LEN(INDEX(r,,c+1))=0), "??",
           INDEX(r,,c) * (INDEX(r,,c+1)="Y") * INDEX(r,,1)))),
       LAMBDA(array, IF(REGEXMATCH(JOIN(,array), "\?"), "??",
         IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(array)))))))))}
```

### Explanation

1. The [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) function passes the range `B3:J` row-by-row into a [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) function.
2. [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) stores the current row in `r`
3. [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) uses [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) function to return:

   1. `??`, where [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en) finds `?` in the string returned by JOINing `r`
   2. else, returns a new (nested) [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) function
4. The nested [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) function's array argument is a [BYCOL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12571032?hl=en) function that passes the array `{2,4,6,8}` column-by-column into a [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en).
5. [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) stores the current column in `c`

   1. Each `c` matches the INDEX/position of a discount column in `r`
   2. The [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en)'s formula returns `??` if there is a value in the column at index `c` but no value in the dropdown at column index `c+1`
   3. Otherwise, returns one of the following, based on the specific formula:

      1. **Discount Formula Returns:**  Discount (column index `c`)
      2. **Tax Savings Formula Returns:** Discount (column index `c`) * Tax rate (column index `1`) * `Pre-tax?` (column index `C+1`).
   4. The `Pre-tax?` calculation `(INDEX(r,,c+1)="Y")` returns `TRUE/FALSE` which Sheets coerces to `1/0` because the calculation expects numbers not text.
   5. The resulting array is a row of values that contains `??` and/or numbers, which is then used as the input array for the parent [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) function's [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en).
6. The [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930?hl=en) function's [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) stores the current row in `array`
7. [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en) uses the [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) function to return:

   1. `??`, where [REGEXMATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en) finds `?` in the string returned by JOINing `array`
   2. else, returns the [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en) of `array`
   3. Lastly, one is divided by the inverse of the value returned by [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669?hl=en).

   - This calculation doesn't affect non-zero numbers but triggers an error for anything else.
   - IFERROR replaces any with a truly blank value.
   - In this way, the original range can be infinite without returning values for blank rows.

     ```
     # Rule
     =IF(ISNUMBER(x)<>0,
         1/(1/x)=x,1/(1/x)=Error

      # x=5
      =IF(ISNUMBER(5)<>0,
          1/(1/5)=5,1/(1/5)=Error
      =1/(1/5)=5
      =5=5
      =TRUE

      # x=BLANK or 0
      =IF(ISNUMBER(0)<>0,
          1/(1/0)=0,1/(1/0)=Error
      =1/(1/0)=Error
      =#DIV/0!=Error 
      =TRUE

      # x="txt"
      =IF(ISNUMBER(0)<>0,
          1/(1/"txt")="txt",1/(1/"txt")=Error 
      =1/(1/"txt")=Error
      =#VALUE!=Error 
      =TRUE
     ```

### 2-Column Variation

This version combines the two calculations and returns a two column array where the discount is the first column and the tax savings is the second.

```
={"Discount","Extra Discount"; BYROW(B3:J, LAMBDA(r, 
   IF(REGEXMATCH(JOIN(,r), "\?"),{"??","??"},
    LET(func,LAMBDA(f, BYROW(
       BYCOL(SEQUENCE(1,4,2,2), LAMBDA(c, 
         IF((LEN(INDEX(r,,c))>0)*(LEN(INDEX(r,,c+1))=0),"??",
           IF(f=1, INDEX(r,,c), INDEX(r,,c) * (INDEX(r,,c+1)="Y") * INDEX(r,,1))))),
       LAMBDA(array, IF(REGEXMATCH(JOIN(,array), "\?"),"??",
         IFERROR(1/(1/SUM(array))))))),{func(1),func(2)}))))}
```